# A word problem related to surface area.

Tags: calculus

> The rectangular front windshield of the bus has a length of $1.5\sqrt{3}m$ and a width of $1.5 m$. Wipers are attached to the bottom corners. If the length of each wiper is equal to the width of the windshield, find the percentage of the windshield that wipers can reach.

At the first glance, I'm sure that the easiest approach to this problem would be using some integration technique. I'm trying to find the area of the region which will be wiped by the wipers so that I can divide it by the total area of the windshield to find the required percentage.

I've created the diagram for the problem as follows:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I can find the area of both the circular quadrant but I don't know how to find the area of common region.
Can anyone help me in this?

---

## **Edit:**

Here's the graph
[image]

Comment: Desmos has its advantages, but for constructing diagrams especially for geometry, GeoGebra is much easier. You just need to choose the tool and then click on the grid to construct circular arcs and other things.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint: break the region up into two circular sectors and a triangle.

Comment: Wow, that's great! But how may I find the angle? Now I'm thinking of finding the intersection point of both the circles and then dropping a perpendicular from the intersection point on the x-axis. and then using formula 1/2 * B * H. Would that be fine? But then it might be difficult to find area of sectors I think.

Comment: Yep, drop a perpendicular and then use right-angled trig.

Comment: By symmetry, the adjacent side to that angle in blue is $1.5 \sqrt{3} /2$.

Comment: Still I'm confused.

Comment: I think finding angle is a must, without angle, I cannot find the area of sector. How to find the angle?

Comment: @user983206 Do you see that the hypotenuse is 1.5 m (because it is also a radius) and that the adjacent side is $1.5 \sqrt{3} /2$?